# OpenSSL Encryption not Compatible with BouncyCastle Decryption?

Tags: android, email, encryption, openssl, bouncycastle

I am sending a encrypted mail using OpenSSL in an android app. 
While sending the mail this is the relevant native code -

```
cipher = EVP_rc2_40_cbc();
int flags = PKCS7_STREAM;
PKCS7* p7 = PKCS7_encrypt(certs, bio, cipher, flags);
int r = SMIME_write_PKCS7(out, p7, bio, flags);
```

The mail is successfully sent to the server and I get a sent mail notification.

Now when I am trying to open the mail using the another android app which has bouncycastle I am unable to open it. It says "Unable to decrypt message."

Also I tried openning the app using the webmail - interface on desktop. Here also I was unable to open the mail.

Any Idea what could be the problem?

I tried using a different cipher also ( 3des ). But that too did not work.

Update -> If I change my encryption code to bouncy castle then everything works fine. I am able to decrypt in both android app and web-browser.  So is there a possibilty that this might be a OpenSSL Issue?

Update 2 -> I tried decrypting the encrypted text using openssl command prompt and it worked. So I guess it is surely some compatibilty problem? But is this a problem with bouncycastle or with openssl ?

Comment: Why do you think that native code is "relevant" when you are experiencing problems on the other side?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - because there is a possibilty that I might be passing the wrong flag. Earlier I ran into such problem in the sending case. Now I am able to send but unable to decrypt.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin -  also because that BouncyCastle code is fully functional and thoroughly tested piece of code. So logically the only problem would be on OpenSSL Side (i.e. sending side).

Comment: It is impossible to say if the encryption side has a "wrong flag" without seeing the decryption side and what "flags" it uses.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - fair point. but atleast I should be able to open the encrypted mail from my web-browser? Even the server is unable to decrypt the message?

Comment: Does the server have the proper key to decrypt it at all?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - Yes! And I am sure because if I comment my OpenSSL Code. And use BouncyCastle for encrypting also then everything works perfectly. Both on the android app and web-browser.

Comment: You should update the question with that info.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - Done. Any help on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a flag.

```
int flags = PKCS7_STREAM | PKCS7_BINARY;
```

This did the charm.